# ionic v3 native camera plugin didn't work on android

Tags: camera, ionic3, ionic-native

using ionic cordova plugin didn't work on open camera or gallery on  android

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : not installed

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

System:

NodeJS : v10.15.3 
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : Windows 10

```js
takePicture() {
        const options: CameraOptions = {
          quality: 75,
          destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI ,
          encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
          sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
          allowEdit: true,
          correctOrientation: true,
          targetWidth: 300,
          targetHeight: 300,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: true
        }

         alert("1");
      this.camera.getPicture(options).then(imageData => {
        
          let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
          this.image = base64Image;
          alert("done");
        }, error => {
      //  Utils.showToast( null,JSON.stringify(error));
        });
        
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

u're missing the most important step,
Make sure you introduce a `camera` in providers in `app.module.ts`

u should create a PictureProvider file like this

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Defer } from '../../common/Defer';
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';

export enum PictureSource {
 PhotoLibrary,
 Camera,
 Local,
 Remote,
}

@Injectable()
export class PictureProvider {

 constructor(private camera: Camera, ) {
  console.log('Hello PictureProvider Provider');
 }

 fromCamera(source: PictureSource, options?, ) {
  let mergedOtions = this.getOptions(source, options);
  if (options)
   for (let k in options)
    mergedOtions[k] = options[k];

  let defer = Defer.create();

  navigator['camera'].getPicture(
   imageUri => defer.resolve(imageUri),
   (message: string) => {
    console.log(message);
    defer.reject();
   },
   mergedOtions,
  );

  return defer.promise;
 }

 private getOptions(source, options?) {
  return {
   sourceType: source == PictureSource.PhotoLibrary ? this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY : this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
   destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
   quality: 50,
   mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
   allowEdit: options.allowEdit,
   correctOrientation: true,
   targetWidth: options.targetWidth,
   targetHeight: options.targetHeight
  }
 }

}
```

Execute as needed

```
this.picture.fromCamera(1, {
        allowEdit: true,
        targetWidth: 256,
        targetHeight: 256,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,  //直接返回base64
    }).then(base64Img => {
        this.headImg = this.encodeBase64Img(base64Img);
    }).catch(Defer.NoOP);
```